# Using Console.Read() to determine end of file C#

Tags: c#, console

A few days ago I've asked a question concerning how to detect an end of input file of N(N is unknown) lines.

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

int endOfFile = 0
while ((endOfFile = Console.Read()) != -1) {
    input.Append(((char)endOfFile).ToString());
    input.Append(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I've edited my question, but I guess this is the same as some of the hints below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Jagannath basically had it, exactly as you asked, except for one little detail: That method works on the console as well, without involving an explicit StreamReader:

```
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // TODO: Add processing
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

If you're typing directly in the console instead of relying on input redirected from a file, press <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> to trigger an "end of file" on the console input. Inside the console, <kbd>F6</kbd> is just a synonym of <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>.

Be aware that <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> here is an interrupt sequence or signal, not an input character. It will show `^Z` on the screen. but you will not receive the `CTRL-Z` (U+001A) character in the program. The <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> sequence is trapped by the console and causes the input stream to close as if the "file had reached the end". **Do not** insert a `CTRL-Z` in the input file.

The origin of using `CTRL-Z` for this purpose goes back to at least the CP/M operating system (a short entertaining story on its own right, but one which is out of scope).

Answer (score 2):

This could help in looping through the file and check for end of file.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"test.txt"))
{
       string line;
       while ( (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine(line);
       }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a link from msdn [ReadLine method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)

Comment: I already knew that. It doesn't work for my case. The user, which is using the program, redirects the input to a file with n number of lines and the program doesn't know when to stop reading.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on using the shell to redirect standard input to your input file?

Why not use something like TextReader.Read() or TextReader.ReadLine()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you're asking this, since the answer you accepted to your previous question is the easiest way to do what you were asking there. Are you just looking for alternate solutions?

You should check the documentation for [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx). In the Remarks it says:

> The ReadKey method reads from the keyboard even if the standard input is redirected to a file with the SetIn method.

`ReadKey` will block until you press a key on the keyboard. You can't use `ReadKey` to detect the end of redirected input.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, I didn't pay much attention to it, thanks! Anyway is there a way to stop reading from a redirected file. Example: you have two files - first file have, let's say, 20 lines and the other 15 lines, what will determine the end of file?

Answer (score 0):

To read input from a file you can use

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines("path/to/file.txt");
```

---

If what you want is to get input from the console character by character, you can do something like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
while ((keyInfo = Console.ReadKey()).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
}
```

You can replace `ConsoleKey.Escape` with any other key, or check for key combinations like CTRL+D, CTRL+C, by using `keyInfo.Modifiers`.